# How to run a Windows Phone 7 PhoneGap app on a device

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova

I have made a html5 app which I have converted into windows app through phonegap.
I want to run it on my windows device but  i don't know to transfer my app to the device and so I am not able to run it on my device.
My device is nokia lumia 720.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not try it my self, but maybe this can help you?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%20Phone